# DataContractJsonSerializer class not found

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I want to serialize my class into JSON by using DataContractJsonSerializer class but when I try to access it in my Console application it is not found in the namespace "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json".
[image: Error]

Please help me so that I can serialize the data using DataContractJsonSerializer class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools >> NuGet Package Manager >> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...

In the "Browse" tab, search for "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" and install it in your project.

In your class file, add `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` or right-click the red squiggly and select "add using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json"